# Postgresql ERROR: cannot drop columns from view

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to postgresql. Can anyone suggest the reason and solution to this error? However it works if I select an extra sum(s.length) but i don't won't this in my results.

code:

```
create or replace view q1("group",album,year) as
    select g.name, a.title, a.year
    from Groups g, Albums a, Songs s
    where a.made_by = g.id and s.on_album = a.id
    group by a.title, g.name, a.year
    order by sum(s.length) desc 
    limit 1;
```

Error message:

> ERROR:  cannot drop columns from view

Comment: Why are you not using proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Answer (score 32):

As It has been mentioned in PostgreSQL documentations:

> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW is similar, but if a view of the same name
> already exists, it is replaced. **The new query must generate the same
> columns that were generated by the existing view query (that is, the
> same column names in the same order and with the same data types), but
> it may add additional columns to the end of the list.** The calculations
> giving rise to the output columns may be completely different.

Reference [Postgres `CREATE VIEW` docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html)

simply put, you can add a new column to the end of existing columns but you can't drop , reorder , rename or change datatype of existing columns.

So in your case, you have to `drop` the whole view and `recreate` it.

Comment: To drop a view, use: `DROP VIEW view_name`

Comment: Curious to know why Postgres put such a restriction? It seems `REPLACE` is just `DROP` + `CREATE`?

Comment: @YihaoGao probably it’s just not implemented in the potsgresql yet . and it's not an easy implementation, It’s actually more complicated than it looks